# Overlapping relationship represented by spring JPA

Tags: database, spring, oracle, jpa

I'm building a webpage backend from scratch as my first practice, using Spring boot, JPA and oracle database. Inside my database, there is a User table containing some information. And there are three other tables, Worker, Customer and Admin. A User can have several roles, for example, User can be both Worker and Admin. (I think it's a overlapping relationship as stated in EER diagram, correct me if I'm wrong)
Now I want to implement this relationship using JPA in Spring boot, but I don't know how exactly should I design the beans. Could someone give me a hint or similar example?

If spring JPA is not a good way to implement this kind of relationship, or if it's too complicate for me to understand. **is there any better way to restructure my database table?**

I've looked into JPA inheritance such as this post [Spring Data Repository with Inheritance.JOINED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701208/spring-data-repository-with-inheritance-joined) but I didn't manage to make my code work, since I don't quite understand the mechanism behind

Here is a example of my database tables:

```
User(Id, username, password, ...)
Worker(Id, user_id, salary, ...)
Admin(Id, user_id, team_name, ...)
Customer(Id, user_id, account_balance, ...)
```

ps: As the homework requirement stated, I'm not suppose to use primary key or foreign key in the database since JPA can handle relationships.

Comment: Share your EER diagram and I don't understand about the primary key or foreign key since they are not optional in JPA.

Comment: JPA builds on top of the database, so you still require a foreign_key relation ship between user and the other tables (what do you think the `user_id` represents in the tables?!). And the recoreds will need a primary-key. What do you think the `id` column represents in each table? Also JPA will not work without a primary key. So not using them simply isn't an  option.

Comment: You will probably want a class hierarchy. Base class User is extended by Worker and Worker is extended by Admin. Given your tables you will want use JPA's JOINED inheritance strategy: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Joined,_Multiple_Table_Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

user-> worker is one-one relationship as a user can be only one worker. the same applies to user-> admin and user-> customer.  you can find mock-up code as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
//... 

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private Worker worker;


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private Admin admin;

// ... getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "worker")
public class Worker {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
//... 
@OneToOne (mappedBy = "worker")
private User user;

}
```